# Yii PHP import CSV fails special characters

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, yii, fgetcsv

I have an import function in my web application (built in Yii) that imports a csv into our database. The entire function itself is quite complicated, splitting in the information into multiple and such.

However, my import excludes foreign characters, have tried converting the values but cant get it to import anything, they simply come through and either '?' or '_'.

The code below is part of my controller that handles the import action.

Worth noting that the my web app interface allows my to copy/paste and create a new record with these characters, so the server itself allows it as does the database, it's just the import that fails.

```
if($csvFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file')) {
          $temp = $csvFile->getTempName();
          $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
          $type = finfo_file($finfo,$temp);
          $row = 1;
          $import = [];
          $model->hasHeaders = $_POST['Import']['hasHeaders'];
          $accepted_file_types = ['text/csv','text/plain','application/vnd.ms-excel'];
          if(in_array($type,$accepted_file_types)) {
            if(($handle = fopen($temp, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
              while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                $row++;
                $array = [];
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    $item = mb_convert_encoding($data[$c], "ISO-8859-1","UTF-8");
                    array_push($array, $item);
                }
                // each line of the CSV becomes an array, each field separated by a comma
                // push the array representing the line to a new array called $import
                array_push($import, $array);
              }
              fclose($handle);
            }
            if($model->hasHeaders) { // slice off first line of array, containing the headers
              array_shift($import);
            }
```

in the for loop, i try transforming the values using mb_convert_encoding, iconv, utf8-encode - either nothing has any effect, or it blanks them instead of recognising the characters.

for more background the test string i'm trying to import is 'Bühnel Svarončík'

Can anyone see what i'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Might you show the queries to the database?

Comment: To be honest, it wouldn't help. As I mentioned, the import to DB is quite complicated, pulling in multiple functions to compile the data, splitting it into different DBs.

Comment: I am testing by outputting this $import and killing the code ( using  print_r and die() ), and it's here that it fails, not inserting to database

Comment: have you tried adding the charset to your connection string? 'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=db;charset=utf8'

Comment: Sorry for the late reply DevAL, yes, charset=UTF8 already in do connection